# Performance difference between RabbitTemplate's waitForConfirms and blocking correlation data callback

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I am implementing a service that needs to publish messages to a RabbitMQ broker in a **reliable and blocking** way. As described in https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-seven-java.html, there are multiple options for publisher confirmation. The most basic option is to use `waitForConfirms`. I tested the following code (with setting `cachingConnectionFactory.setPublisherConfirmType(CachingConnectionFactory.ConfirmType.SIMPLE)`) and it took about 100 seconds to publish 10,000 of these messages:

```java
rabbitTemplate.invoke(rabbitOperations -> {
  rabbitOperations.convertAndSend("test_exchange", "test_key", "test message");
  return rabbitOperations.waitForConfirms(1000);
});
```

I also tested the asynchronous option (with setting `cachingConnectionFactory.setPublisherConfirmType(CachingConnectionFactory.ConfirmType.CORRELATED)`) with a very primitive blocking wrapper. The following code took about 20 seconds to publish 10,000 messages:

```java
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
CorrelationData correlationData = new CorrelationData();
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("test_exchange", "test_key", "test message", correlationData);
correlationData.getFuture().addCallback(success -> {
  latch.countDown();
}, failure -> {
  latch.countDown();
});
latch.await();
```

As far as I understand the following quote in the above link, my first example should basically do the same that my second example does.

> Think of waitForConfirmsOrDie as a synchronous helper which relies on asynchronous notifications under the hood.

But the performance difference is too massive for my assumption to be true. I see that `RabbitTemplate.invoke` executes a lot more stuff than my second code example. But what exactly is the reason for this massive performance difference? Is my second example bad practice, or is my first example in some unnecessary way inefficient?

**EDIT**
Copy-pasting the code from Gary, I experienced the following:

```
StopWatch '': running time = 106379462700 ns
---------------------------------------------
ns         %     Task name
---------------------------------------------
17546479900  016 %  correlated
88832982800  084 %  simple
```

I am using Windows 10 Pro, RabbitMQ 3.8.9 running via `docker run -it --rm --name rabbitmq -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:3-management`, and Spring Boot 2.3.1

**EDIT 2**
Adding `RabbitUtils.isPhysicalCloseRequired()` to the simple confirmation code of Gary:

```java
simpleTemplate.invoke(ops -> {
  ops.convertAndSend("so64857773", "test message");
  RabbitUtils.isPhysicalCloseRequired();
  return ops.waitForConfirms(1000);
});
```

yields the following results:

```
StopWatch '': running time = 46090067400 ns
---------------------------------------------
ns         %     Task name
---------------------------------------------
21100935900  046 %  correlated
24989131500  054 %  simple
```

It seems that when running a dockerized version of RabbitMQ on Windows, closing and recreating a channel is quite expensive.

**EDIT 3**
Using a native Windows 10 RabbitMQ server (3.8.9) with Erlang 23.1.3, performance massively increased. Using 10k messages, the correlated confirm test took only around 3 seconds. I increased the number of messages for the following two tests to 50k.

First test, with the original code from Gary:

```
StopWatch '': running time = 144403128200 ns
---------------------------------------------
ns         %     Task name
---------------------------------------------
19750222900  014 %  correlated
124652905300  086 %  simple
```

Second test, with `RabbitUtils.isPhysicalCloseRequired()` added as described in EDIT 2:

```
StopWatch '': running time = 30030523500 ns
---------------------------------------------
ns         %     Task name
---------------------------------------------
14549132300  048 %  correlated
15481391200  052 %  simple
```

Closing and reopening a channel seems to be very expensive on Windows - it does not seem to be a problem with using the dockerized version.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot more code involved with correlated confirms, so I would have expected that version to take more time (although not a huge difference).

I am not sure why you are seeing the behavior you observe.

However, in both cases, it's better to send multiple requests before waiting for the confirms; sending and waiting for each one will be significantly slower.

With correlated confirms, you can save off the `CorrelationData` instances and wait for the futures later.

**EDIT**

I am not seeing the same behavior as you; I get nearly identical performance using both methods; about 62 seconds in each case.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So64857773Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So64857773Application.class, args);
    }

//  @Bean
//  Queue queue() {
//      return new Queue("so64857773");
//  }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(CachingConnectionFactory cf, RabbitTemplate template) {
        return args -> {
            StopWatch watch = new StopWatch();
            cf.createConnection().close();
            watch.start("correlated");
            for (int i = 0; i < 10_000; i++) {
                CorrelationData cd = new CorrelationData();
                template.convertAndSend("", "so64857773", "test message", cd);
                cd.getFuture().get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            };
            watch.stop();

            cf.resetConnection();
            cf.setPublisherConfirmType(ConfirmType.SIMPLE);
            RabbitTemplate simpleTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(cf);
            cf.createConnection().close();
            watch.start("simple");
            for (int i = 0; i < 10_000; i++) {
                simpleTemplate.invoke(ops -> {
                    ops.convertAndSend("so64857773", "test message");
                    return ops.waitForConfirms(1000);
                });
            };
            watch.stop();

            System.out.println(watch.prettyPrint());
        };
    }

}
```

```
spring.rabbitmq.publisher-confirm-type=correlated
```

Result:

```
StopWatch '': running time = 124245233864 ns
---------------------------------------------
ns         %     Task name
---------------------------------------------
62136894432  050%  correlated
62108339432  050%  simple
```

Comment: Gary, thanks for the answer. I tried the simple confirm method with waiting for confirms after every 10th message, and the time dropped from 100s to 6s. However, waiting for confirms every x messages is not viable for me, because it may happen that my service does not send a message for a few minutes (depending on load). And I need a reliable confirmation within a few seconds

Comment: I am getting nearly identical performance for both methods (a very slight additional overhead for corrrelated confirms, as I expected). See the edit to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look into this. I copy-pasted your code, and I am experiencing very different results to yours. I updated my question with a few more details. Do you have any idea what could cause this massive difference?

Comment: Wow; I have no idea how/why that would happen. My broker is running natively on MacOS (via HomeBrew). What platform are you running on? `waitForConfirms` does have some code synchronization; maybe that's the problem; you could try profiling the app. You could also add similar code to your correlated example, using `synchronized/wait/notify` instead of the `CountDownLatch` to see if that brings them closer. If so, you need to figure out why synchronization is so expensive on your machine.

Comment: Im running Rabbit MQ inside docker on a Windows 10 Pro machine (see my edit). Could you give me a tip on how to profile that? I just used JFR to profile the application run, but I was not able to see useful output.. at least not useful in my understanding

Comment: Sorry; I am not familiar with JFR, I use YourKit for profiling.

Comment: I tried YourKit, and I still don't see anything really useful. The application is mostly just waiting. In the simple confirm approach, the application (or the broker, I dont know) seems to close and reopen a whole channel for each message. Might this be a cause? Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: Yes; with scoped operations (`template.invoke()`) we do close the channel after each operation - to avoid leaking confirms between invocations - but, as can be seen by my test, channel creation is pretty cheap. Perhaps it has something to do with your dockerized broker? Maybe try with a local broker? You can disable the channel closing by calling `RabbitUtils.isPhysicalCloseRequired()` (versions < 2.3.1) or `RabbitUtils.clearPhysicalCloseRequired()` (2.3.1 or later) inside the `invoke` callback.

Comment: I experienced very different results after adding `RabbitUtils.isPhysicalCloseRequired()`. The performance is almost the same. See my edit. This might have to do with docker, as you said. I will try with a local broker.